# How to display 10 records per page from resultset?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, resultset

I have 100 records(rows) in my database table and I want to display 10 records from that table per page.I want to display the records from database as the following manners.

***----- NEXT 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 PREVIOUS---------***

When we click on label 1 it will display first 10 records(1 to 10) from database table.Again when we click on 2 it will show records from 11 to 20 from database table and so on.

When we click on **NEXT** and **PREVIOUS**,it will show next page and previous page from the current page respectively.For example suppose current page display records from ***41-50*** then when we click on **NEXT** it will show records from ***51-60*** and when we click on **PREVIOUS** it will show records from ***31-40***.

Comment: Use `limit` and `offset` in query.

Comment: Here is some example about it >http://theopentutorials.com/post/uncategorized/pagination-in-servlet-and-jsp/

Comment: google pagination and you should be able to find the answers you need e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination

Answer (score 0):

Do not re-invent the wheel.. use data tables, highly recommended, it has ajax based sorting, searching and client side pagination. You can even use server side validation (hope you understand it).

This is the simple example, try it out.

```
http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/dom.html (matches your requirement 100%)
```

You can even export the grid result to xls and pdf.